Outlook 365 vs Outlook 2021 (Search)
I am new to this forum; this will be my first question, sorry if i'm missing things to tell.
I have an issue with Outlook 2021 searching. (uptodate)
Serverside is Exchange box in Exchange Server 2019.(uptodate)
I don't use caching, so the search engine/index is used from the server.
The issue:
We have a folder with 16 mails in the mailbox.
All the mails have atleast "824" in the subject of all the 16 mails. from these 16 mails, also 14 mails have the word "Control"
When I do a search in the search bar at top and search in current folder; on "824" it finds 5 mails. (Which is weird, because all 16 have these keyword)
When I do a search in the bar at top and search in current folder; on "Control" it finds all 14.
Which is correct.
When I do both searches in OWA, I get good hits of both keywords. So the indexing of Exchange is OK.
I have built a test pc with Outlook 365 (uptodate) (With same mailbox on Exchange 2019)
Then it's also showing good results like OWA on both hits. That also makes me more sure that the serverside is ok.
The funny part to know, Outlook also has an option to search advanced, with an advanced popup; "Search Criteria"
If I use that one, BOTH versions have the issue of getting limited results.
Conclusion for me:

Serverside is ok
It looks like Outlook 365 (the search bar at top) has a better / renewed engine.
Compared to Outlook 2021.

I was wondering, if anyone has more tips about this and why this is. I read on Google that ofcourse 365 is better updated/maintained. I believe that, but why should this simple search does not give the good results.
Hope anyone has tips!
Regards Marco

Verify that the search syntax you're using is correct and consistent across both versions of Outlook. Sometimes, subtle differences in how the search query is entered can affect the results.
Office 365 (now Microsoft 365) is continually updated, but standalone versions such as Outlook 2021 may not receive updates as frequently, which may result in differences in performance and functionality (including search capabilities).

Yes, I just only type the simple "824" or "Control" (Without the quotes..)
It looks like a difference in version of Office, only in the search bar of 365.
I just dont understand why such simple search syntax does not give good results.
I hope someone has any idea about it.. Especially because Office 2021 + Exchange 2019 is quite common for companies who bought the software.

This may relate to the fact that Outlook 365 has a different search logic than Outlook 2021.
